# Typed Hierarchical Access Control System

Tags: haskell

How can I define a simple hierarchical access control system in Haskell?

My roles are `Public > Contributor > Owner`, these roles are in a hierarchy. Everything that can be done by `Public` can also be done by `Contributor` and `Owner`; and so on.

Similarly Operations are also in a hierarchy: `None > View > Edit`. If a Role is permitted to Edit, it should also be able to View.

```hs
data Role = Public | Contributor | Owner
data Operation = None | View | Edit

newtype Policy = Policy (Role -> Operation)
```

In this system I can express public editable policy as:

```hs
publicEditable :: Policy
publicEditable = Policy $ const Edit
```

But type system does not prevent me from defining stupid policies like this (that permits `Public` to `Edit` but denies any access to the `Owner`):

```hs
stupidPolicy :: Policy
stupidPolicy = Policy check where
  check Public      = Edit
  check Contributor = View
  check Owner       = None
```

How can I express the hierarchical nature of Role and Operation in the type system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anyone with access to `Policy`'s constructors can take a `Policy` apart and put it back together, possibly in a nonsensical fashion. Don't expose the `Policy` constructor outside of this module. Instead, provide a [*smart constructor*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors) to create policies that are guaranteed to be well-formed and expose a `Monoid` interface to compose them without breaking invariants. Keeping the `Policy` type abstract ensures that all the code which could result in nonsensical policies is kept inside this module.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Policy (
    Role(..),
    Level(..),
    Policy,  -- keep Policy abstract by not exposing the constructor
    can
    ) where

import Data.Semigroup (Semigroup, Max(..))

data Role = Public | Contributor | Owner
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum, Show, Read)
data Level = None | View | Edit
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum, Show, Read)
```

Below I'm using [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-derived-instances-for-newtypes) to borrow a pair of `Monoid` instances from `base`: [the monoid for functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-268), which lifts another monoid through the function arrow point-wise, and [the `Max` newtype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Max), which turns an `Ord` instance into a `Monoid` instance by always choosing the larger of `mappend`'s arguments.

So `Policy`'s `Monoid` instance will automatically manage the ordering of `Level` when composing policies: when composing two policies with conflicting levels at a given role we'll always choose the more permissive one. This makes `<>` an *additive* operation: you define policies by adding permissions to the "default" policy, `mempty`, which is the one which grants no permissions to anyone.

```
newtype Policy = Policy (Role -> Max Level) deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
```

`grant` is a *smart constructor* which produces policies which respect the ordering properties of `Role` and `Level`. Note that I'm comparing roles with `>=` to ensure that granting a permission to a role also grants that permission to more privileged roles.

```
grant :: Role -> Level -> Policy
grant r l = Policy (Max . pol)
    where pol r'
            | r' >= r   = l
            | otherwise = None
```

`can` is an *observation* which tells you whether a policy grants a given access level to a given role. Once more I'm using `>=` to ensure that more-permissive levels imply less-permissive ones.

```
can :: Role -> Level -> Policy -> Bool
(r `can` l) (Policy f) = getMax (f r) >= l
```

I was pleasantly surprised by how little code this module took! Leaning on the `deriving` mechanism, especially `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, is a really nice way of putting the types in charge of "boring" code so you can focus on the important stuff.

---

Usage of these policies looks like this:

```
module Client where

import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Policy
```

You can use the `Monoid` class to build complex policies out of simple ones.

```
ownerEdit, contributorView, myPolicy :: Policy

ownerEdit = grant Owner Edit
contributorView = grant Contributor View
myPolicy = ownerEdit <> contributorView
```

And you can use the `can` function to test policies.

```
canPublicView :: Policy -> Bool
canPublicView = Public `can` View
```

For example:

```
ghci> canPublicView myPolicy
False
```

Comment: Am I right that GHC is able to derive a Monoid instance for `Policy` because `Max a` is a Monoid and `x -> Monoid y` is a Monoid. I can also derive my own ` instance: ```(Policy a) `mappend` (Policy b) = Policy $ \r -> max (a r) (b r) ```

Comment: Yes, though GHC will generate exactly the same code, so why bother writing it?

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Benjamin Hodgson's solution is simpler and more elegant, but here's a type-level programming solution, using the machinery of the `singletons` package.

The idea is that policies are represented as type-level lists of `(Role, Operation)` tuples, where both the `Role`s and the `Operation`s must be nondecreasing across the list. That way, we can't have an absurd `[(Public,Edit),(Owner,View)]` permission.

Some required extensions and imports:

```
{-# language PolyKinds #-}
{-# language DataKinds #-}
{-# language TypeFamilies #-}
{-# language GADTs #-}
{-# language TypeOperators #-}
{-# language UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# language FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# language ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# language TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.TH
import Data.Promotion.Prelude (Unzip)
```

We declare the datatypes and singletonize them using Template Haskell:

```
data Role = Public | Contributor | Owner deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
data Operation = None | View | Edit deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
$(genSingletons       [''Role,''Operation])
$(promoteEqInstances  [''Role,''Operation])
$(promoteOrdInstances [''Role,''Operation])
```

A class for lists with nondecreasing elements:

```
class Monotone (xs :: [k])
instance Monotone '[]
instance Monotone (x ': '[])
instance ((x :<= y) ~ True, Monotone (y ': xs)) => Monotone (x ': y ': xs)
```

Given a policy specified as a type-level list, return the policy function:

```
policy :: forall (xs :: [(Role, Operation)]) rs os. 
             (Unzip xs ~ '(rs,os), Monotone rs, Monotone os) 
       => Sing xs
       -> Role 
       -> Operation
policy singleton role = 
    let decreasing = reverse (fromSing singleton)
        allowed = dropWhile (\(role',_) -> role' > role) decreasing
    in case allowed of
        [] -> None
        (_,perm) : _ -> perm
```

Testing it in ghci:

```
ghci> :set -XDataKinds -XPolyKinds -XTypeApplications
ghci> policy (sing::Sing '[ '(Public,View),'(Owner,Edit) ]) Owner
Edit
ghci> policy (sing::Sing '[ '(Public,Edit),'(Owner,View) ]) Owner
*unhelpful type error*
```

Comment: excellent comparison. still juggling with the static / dynamic design space